# F# + MPI + MONO : Clustered Computing

Tags: .net, f#, mpi, cluster-computing

Is it possible for F# and MPI to run off of Mono on a linux computational cluster?  Anyone able to attest to it's performance/reliability?

Comment: Just curious, why not just use ocaml if you're on linux? Must be because you are running some already written F# code??

Comment: Well, I am a .NET developer of 5 years.  so anything I can carry over I would like to.  Is ocaml a particularly good language in place of f# on a cluster?

Comment: F# is based on ocaml and the ML family. It's often cited as being very quick. Although you don't have the .NET hooks (well, they're working on that). ocaml has MPI hooks that work well on clusters. ocaml is also multi-platform.

Comment: Thank you.  Were you referring to this compiler? http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~montela/ocamil/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done some basic tests with F# and Mono 2.0 and everything worked well. I know others have done much deeper test that me and have run into a few bugs, but mostly report a positive experience (plus the mono and F# teams are quite responsive to bug reports).

I haven't test MPI.NET at all, but they say it does run under mono: http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/faq/?category=general

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  Do you recal what kinds of issues they hit?

Answer (score 1):

Hm. According to this bug: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=419828 even a basic definition of a map function fails with F# on Mono. Doesn't look like a very stable combination right now.

Comment: Thanks Anon, that is unfortunate :/